# Dosbase application on windows xp problems

Tags: windows, windows-xp, dos

all dos base application experts here is one thread i am creating.
i would like your opinion for this issues

i found one problem in windows xp or any windows system higher to windows 98
i have a dos base application which runs perfect on windows 98 but when i am running it on windows xp or other system it is showing me following error message

**16 bit Ms-Dos Subsystem**

**An application has attemped to directly access the hard disk, which cannot
be supported. This may cause the application to function incorrectly.
Choose close to terminate the application**

as i can run it by pressing ignore but want to remove this error message

second thing i found is **dos base printing**
printing is not working properly

as it prints some part then it pause for some time and then resume printing

so how to solve these problems.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I suggest posting more detail about the problems you're experiencing, especially the verbatim error messages you're seeing.

Comment: i am getting following error      "16-bit MS-DOS Subsystem path to the program that you are trying to start or install C:\Windows\System32\config.nt The system file is not suitable for running MS-DOS and Microsoft Windows applications. Choose 'Close' to terminate the application."

Comment: and another issue when dos base application is going to print on dot matrix printer it prints and stop for few second in one print command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An application has attemped to directly access the hard disk, which cannot be supported.

This error means exactly what it says. Older versions of Windows including 95/98/Me gave DOS programs full control over the system, meaning they could access hardware as they wished -- while this maintained compatibility with older programs, it could also cause the entire OS to crash if this one program did something wrong.

The Windows NT family (including XP and all newer versions) runs DOS programs in an NTVDM (NT virtual DOS machine) which does not have direct access to hardware, and any attempt by programs to access such things will cause the program to be terminated. Of course, you can ignore the error, but your program will likely not work correctly.